# Recording System Audio using WASAPI and Port Audio doesn't record Skype but records others

Tags: windows-10, drivers, skype, audio-recording, skype-for-business

I have developed a program that records my system audio in Python using PyAudio. However, I notice that it records everything except for Skype call audio (and that is really the audio I want to record). All other sounds that I play through my speakers (like web videos, internal media player) successfully get recorded. I am using the WASAPI driver on my speaker to do this through a loopback.

My question is, is it possible that Skype is forcing audio through another audio driver to get to my speakers, not through the WASAPI driver I am using to record and that's why I am not capturing it?

If so, is there a way to set a particular audio driver as the default for the system so all sound can go through my WASAPI driver?

Or am I thinking about this completely wrong?

Here is a list of my system audio devices (this is a virtualized Windows 10 machine, so it doesn't have standard hardware tied to it).

Here is a list of all audio devices recognized by my application. In the list, I am sampling and capturing sound from ID 8:

```
0:       Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input
         MME

1:       Headset Microphone (Plantronics
         MME

2:       Microphone Array (Realtek High
         MME

3:       Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output
         MME

4:       Headset Earphone (Plantronics C
         MME

5:       LG ULTRAWIDE (Intel(R) Display
         MME

6:       Speakers / Headphones (Realtek
         MME

7:       LG ULTRAWIDE (Intel(R) Display
         Windows WASAPI

8:       Headset Earphone (Plantronics C
         Windows WASAPI

9:       Headset Microphone (Plantronics
         Windows WASAPI

10:      Microphone Array (Realtek High
         Windows WASAPI

11:      Speakers / Headphones (Realtek
         Windows WASAPI
```

Comment: My initial thought was that Skype would try to block the audio from being recorded directly, for privacy and audio recording law compliance. I think when you record within the Skype app, the other party needs to provide consent. It has been awhile since I've used Skype now. There are a lot of posts on StackOverflow about this exact question, recording Skype using Python in Windows. Granted a lot of them are pretty old, The SoundAnalyze library linked in a couple posts on SO looks interesting, as the docs for it say it was built for realtime microphone input for games. Hope this is helpful.